# Using the Maven Link V1 API with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I wanted to share this and also seek testing by others to hone this code. If you use maven link, this may be helpful to you in making a project on there from an online form. We use the form submission to do several internal functions with our file sever and the like.

At any rate here is the code. Further testing needs done specifically around the PUT function:

```
///// CREATE THE MAVEN LINK PROJECT /////


function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
        if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

// MAKE SURE CURL DOES NOT OUTPUT TO PAGE
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   //SET HEADERS FOR AUTH
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer !---INSERT-0-AUTH-TOKEN---!', 'Expect:'
));

//PUT REQUIRES ADDITIONAL HEADERS
if ($method == "PUT") 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT',
'Authorization: Bearer !---INSERT-0-AUTH-TOKEN---!', 'Expect:'
));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$vars = curl_exec($curl);

return $vars;
}
// CREATE THE WORKSPACE: NOTE, I left my post variables in here - however should be noted that a script was used (not included) to ensure against injection.
// build the data according to the jason standards for mavenlink's API
$Data = array('workspace[title]' => $_POST['Description'], 'workspace[creator_role]'=> "maven", 'workspace[description]'=> strip_tags($_POST['Details']), 'workspace[price]'=>$_POST['CostBudget'], 'workspace[due_date]'=>date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['ProjectDue'])), 'workspace[project_tracker_template_id]'=> "285045" );

$DecodeMe = CallAPI("POST","https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspaces.json",$Data);
$Decoded = json_decode($DecodeMe,true); // be sure to set the option to true so your array comes back as associative


// INVITE USERS:

//////// BASE USERS

$InviteUrl = "https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspaces/".$Decoded['results'][0]['id']."/invite.json";


$Data2 = array('invitation[full_name]' => "User Fullname", 'invitation[email_address]'=> "email@email.com", 'invitation[invitee_role]'=> "maven" );
$Decoded2 = json_decode(CallAPI("POST",$InviteUrl,$Data2),true);
```

// repeat the above or use a do while script to process more.

```
// THE END
```